# Начисление знаков и их отображение в профиле

Tags: поддержка, знаки

На данный момент имею больше 80 отредактированных сообщений и ответов на русском сегменте стека, но метка "Редактор" так и не начислена в мой профиль, хотя в списке полученных отмечена птицей. Есть ли определенное время получения знаков?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в списке знаков - его так же нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подождите хотя бы до серверной полночи. Знаки присваиваются с небольшой задержкой, но я ещё не видел случая, чтобы вовсе не присвоились.

Comment: Дайте кешу обновиться, не уйдёт от вас ваш значок, не волнуйтесь.

Comment: Вот он и появился)

Comment: [Все на месте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white?userid=206432)

Comment: да, пришлось ждать около 20 минут для присвоения. Это время где-то регламентировано и описано?

Comment: @YuriiManziuk я бы не стал такое регламентировать на месте руководства Stack Exchange. Фича бесплатная, зачем на неё вводить жёсткий SLA? Потом ещё придётся поддерживать, претензии читать. ))

Comment: с регламентированием я перегнул, но хотя бы в справке по получению знаков я бы написал, что они могут быть присвоены "в течении некоторого времени"

Comment: @YuriiManziuk согласен, хорошо бы прямо на странице знаков влепить ссылку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из [ответа](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23089/339911) на MSE:

> Other badges (mostly the ones which can only be awarded once, like the specialist badges) are awarded by a background process which appears to run only once a day. According to TheTXI (comment below), this seems to happen at 0:00 UTC (at least on meta), but since we don't have an official word on this, it's hard to say whether it's the same for all sites or is consistent. However, it's safe to say that after 24 hours, if you still don't have your badge, something is amiss.

следует, что некоторые знаки присуждаются с задержкой, которая может составлять до 24 часов. Перерасчёт скорее всего происходит в районе серверной полуночи (0:00 UTC). Т.о. иногда нужно просто подождать. Если за сутки ожидаемый знак так и не был вручен, имеет смысл перепроверить выполнение всех условий для вручения знака и если они всё же выполнены - можно смело задавать вопрос на Мете.